# generate CMakeList.text for OS X

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to create a plugin for OBS using C, and compiling it using `cmake .. && make` see - https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#mac-osx

when running `cmake .. && make` from cmd it gives me an error that `cmake: command not found` and when I run it from the program it gives me an error - `CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/gerwin/Desktop/soOBS" does not appear to contain CMakeList.text specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the cmake GUI`

How can I generate a CMakeList.Text to compile my soOBS script to a .so file?

Comment: Do you have `cmake` installed, and in your path? And you can't "generate" a `CMakeList.txt`. It's a build file. You have write it, to tell cmake how to compile your project.

Comment: yeah I can open the GUI for cmake & how can I write the cmake file? a quick google search looks extremely complex

Comment: Yes, `cmake` is an extremely complex piece of software. Not sure if I get your question right, do you want to compile obs-studio, or a standalone project, using the API of obs-studio?

Comment: I want to compile a stand-alone project, to .so this is so that OBS can load the .so file. I've used the - http://preetisblog.com/programming/how-to-write-cmakelists-txt guide but I'm getting an error - Parse Error. Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "{rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoaarf1404\cocoasubrtf130".

Comment: Just use set your PATH in right way `export PATH=$PATH:path/to/cmake/binary`

Comment: @Gerwin You don't have to use cmake, though. You can simply use the build system of your choice to build the shared library. A simple makefile would suffice.

Comment: how would I go about creating said makefile?

Comment: nmake -f Makefile.MSVC CPU=P3 @Leandros running this command returns a nmake: command not found.. - https://jp9000.github.io/OBS/general/development.html

Comment: You should probably read how to compile a shared library, before trying to build something using it.

Comment: @Leandros alright I'll google around a bit and see if I can find something usefull, thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that `cmake` is not in your path. So, if you type `cmake` from your command line it cannot be found. The other problem is that you are not specifying correctly your source directory: you have to specify as source directory the location of the main/root `CMakeLists.txt`.

So, proceed as follow:

- Locate your cmake executable, obtaining your `<full path to cmake>`
- Open a shell
- Go to your source directory (location of the main/root of obs-studio `CMakeLists.txt`)
- `mkdir build`
- `cd build`
- `<full path to cmake> ..`
  The first argument `..` is your source directory, location of the main `CMakeLists.txt`
- `make`